# Magic file does not produces wanted results

Tags: command-line, files

I got two files:

1. `$cat myMagic
   20    string    TEST    ThisIsTestType`
2. `$cat testFile
                   TEST i am test file from inside`

Both files are in same directory.I run:

`$file testFile
 testFile: ASCII text`

Why I'm getting `ASCII text`and not getting `testFile: ThisIsTestType`?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`file` uses its pre-compiled magic database by default - you need to tell it to use your custom file using the `-m` option.

Ex.

```
$ file testFile
testFile: ASCII text
```

but

```
$ file -m myMagic testFile
testFile: ThisIsTestType
$
```